# Why do my project references passthrough to other references

Tags: c#, .net-standard, csproj

We have started migrating to the new project type for .NET Standard and have used the tool that Hanselman linked in [this blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpgradingAnExistingNETProjectFilesToTheLeanNewCSPROJFormatFromNETCore.aspx).

One peculiar thing we noticed is that a project now receives references to projects that it's references have. I have setup a sample and confirmed that it is not just our main application. For the main application, let's say we have

> Console App: TestingSomeStuff
>
> Net standard library: Library1
>
> Net standard library: Library2

In this situation, we have the following references:

> TestingSomeStuff -> Library1 -> Library2

For some reason, `TestingSomeStuff`, which does not directly reference `Library2` is able to access types in `Library2`, and this just seems incorrect.  I setup the same situation in a .NET Framework application and `TestingSomeStuff` does not have access to `Library2`.

In order to build an appropriately layered application, we need the ability to block `TestingSomeStuff` from accessing `Library2` as a passthrough and I cannot find any information on how to approach that.

I have tried setting `IncludeAssets`, `ExcludeAssets` and other options similar to that but nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you tried setting `PrivateAssets="All"`?

Answer (score 1):

This is new to the new MSBuild projects for .NET Core. If you want to hide something, mark it as `internal` in Library2 and use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute and give Library1 access.

Comment: Is there a new keyword we can use for actual internal classes then?

Comment: @DanDrews nope.

Comment: That is unfortunate

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out what was going on here, it was completely my mistake but I'm leaving the question un-deleted for the community. I was wrong in the statement that "ExcludeAssets" all did not work.

The issue was that the setup was more complicated than my sample project, Really what we had was:

> TestingSomeStuff
>
> -Library1
>
> --Library3
>
> -Library2
>
> --Library3

I was only testing ExcludeAssets=All on Library1, so it was still referencing it through the reference to Library2.